# jQuery dynamicly element mouseout-mouseover events

Tags: jquery

Below codes are working when mouse on the current **li** tag and out the **li** tag. The mouseover function create a **img** tag in **li** tag when i drag mouse to this new **img** tag mouseout function works. But the new "**img**" tag in the current "**li**" tag this is not out of "**li**" tag. Where is my problem?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("div.Michaela ul li").on("mouseover",function(){
            if(!$(this).find("span img").length){
                $(this).find("span").append("<img src='http://cupios.com/app_theme/cupios/images/pen_icon.png'>");
            }
        });

        $("div.Michaela ul li").on("mouseout",function(){
            $(this).find("span img").remove();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) syntax of on is

```
$(static-ancestor).on(event, dynamic-element-selector, handler)
```

so if the `div` is static element then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div.Michaela").on("mouseover", ' ul li', function () {
        if (!$(this).find("span img").length) {
            $(this).find("span").append("<img src='http://cupios.com/app_theme/cupios/images/pen_icon.png'>");
        }
    }).on("mouseout", ' ul li', function () {
        $(this).find("span img").remove();
    });
});
```

another syntax to write the same is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div.Michaela").on({
        mouseover: function () {
            if (!$(this).find("span img").length) {
                $(this).find("span").append("<img src='http://cupios.com/app_theme/cupios/images/pen_icon.png'>");
            }
        },
        mouseout: function () {
            $(this).find("span img").remove();
        }
    }, ' ul li');
});
```

If the `div` also is dynamic the bind the event to `document` and them move the div selector `div.Michaela` to dynamic element selector like

```
$(document).on(event, 'div.Michaela ul li', handler)
```

Comment: Yes, div is static. The codes is not solved the problem. You may try create a new user with random informations on the cupios.com and may come to step 3 these codes there working.